# Is there a way to sort based on an optional property

Tags: swift

As you can see, I'm trying to sort an array in viewDidLoad based on `matchDate`, an optional property. The compiler is forcing me to unwrap it. I was wondering if there was a way to sort this array without unwrapping it?

```
  struct match {
  var matchDate: Date?
  }
   class vc: UIViewController {
   let array = [match]() 

       override func viewDidLoad() {

     let sorted = array.sorted { $0.matchDate! < $1.matchDate!} 
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is going to crash with those force-unwraps in place.

Comment: yeah, i know.. hence the question